# Build a dataframe from uneven nested list of dictionary key value pairs and json

Tags: json, pandas, dictionary, nested-lists

Sorry to bother u guys again. Below is my Json output (which I have put into a variable for convenience) from Azure form recognizer extract :

```
Service_Table =  {
                        
                        "valueArray": [{"type": "object",
                                   "valueObject": {
                                    "Minimum Connections": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "valueString": "290",
                                        "content": "290"},
                                    "Plan name": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "valueString": "Endless Plan",
                                        "content": "Endless Plan"}}},   
                                {"type": "object",
                                "valueObject": {
                                    "Plan name": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "valueString": "Corporate Plan",
                                        "content": "Corporate Plan"}}}]}
```

As you can see it is a nested list containing key value pairs. I need to get the dataframe out of this as follows:

[image]

I've tried many things such as pd.DataFrame(ServiceTable), pd.json_normalize(ServiceTable) other list comprehension methods etc but not able to get what I need, because the key value pairs are uneven (inside the first "valueOject" you can see two keys while in the second one there is only one key). Any help here is really appreciated and thank you for your time.

For more clarity the key "valueObject" could be accessed by calling Service['valueArray'][i] where i is the index (there are two keys with name valueObject)

Comment: why doesn't `pd.json_normalize(Service_Table["valueArray"])` work? It also gives additional columns but you can still get min con and plan name

Comment: @ Nuri Tas thanks for that. Didn't think of that at the first place. Anyway, the output I e shown here is a microcosm. In reality if I create the same from the exact valueArray output I'll end up with 50 columns. Any suggestions to get the exact key value pair in the column and row , you are welcome 

Answer (score 1):

I would prepare a dictionary first:

```
content = [
    (values.get('Minimum Connections', dict()).get('content'),
     values.get('Plan name', dict()).get('content'))
    for xs in Service_Table.get('valueArray', [])
    for key, values in xs.items()
    if key == 'valueObject']

rows = {i: (i + 1,) + content[i] for i in range(len(content))}
```

Then create a DataFrame from with `from_dict`:

```
(pd.DataFrame
 .from_dict(rows,
            orient='index',
            columns=['S.no', 'Minimum Connections', 'Plan name'])
 .astype({'Minimum Connections': 'Int32'}))
```

The result table:

```
   S.no  Minimum Connections       Plan name
0     1                  290    Endless Plan
1     2                 <NA>  Corporate Plan
```

*Note: I would suggest to remove spaces from the column name.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pandas.json_normalize`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) :

```
df = pd.json_normalize(Service_Table['valueArray'])
df = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.endswith('content')]

df.columns = range(df.columns.size)

df.insert(0, 'S.no', df.index+1)
df = df.rename(columns= {0: 'Minimum connections', 1: 'Plan name'})
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   S.no Minimum connections       Plan name
0     1                 290    Endless Plan
1     2                 NaN  Corporate Plan
```

Comment: Thanks Abokey. That's a cool soln.